# How to replace similar meaning words with a common synonym in a text

Tags: python, synonym

I am doing a project where I have to make a graph out of words of a text. I want to replace similar meaning words with a common synonym. For example, if a text has the occurences of 'Murder', 'Kill' and 'slay'. I want to replace all of these with a common synonym (which may have a little different meaning) like 'Kill'. How can I do this in Python?

I have tried NLTK synsets, but could not come up with a way so that all similar words are replaced with synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple machine learning problem. Use any clustering algorithm.

Convert words to vectors, and group similar words based on their vector plot.
Select one word from each cluster to replace with its similar words.